# How to get instance of SensorManager

Tags: android, sensors

I want to get instance of `SensorManager`. What should I write instead of `SENSOR_SERVICE` below? If it is name of registered service what add to Manifest.xml?

`mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`

I have been using code from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

EDIT: There is no such method as: `getSystemService(....);`

EDIT2: Will this do: `ctx.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);`?

Answer (score 1):

All Context's have that function.  You need to either call it in a Context class (Activity or Service) or call it on a reference to one (context.getSystemService())

Comment: Fount it out 30 seconds ago, they suppose to inform about it in documentation to SensorManager.